# Jenkins-Build when a change is pushed to GitHub option is not working

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

Jenkins is running on localhost.
I have my repository in GitHub. I have the option to 'Build when a change is pushed to GitHub' checked.

When I click 'Build Now', build is done successfully, no issues there. But when am committing code to my repository, auto build is not happening. I can access GitHub from my system as the repository is public and I believe even Jenkins should be able to detect it. I know there is a polling option but I want Jenkins to  build when change is detected in repository(as this is what we have been trying to achieve).

**Configuration:**

*Jenkins 1.615*

*Git Plugin 2.3.5*

*Git Client Plugin 1.17.1*

————————————————————————————————————————————

**EDIT**: "*Build when a change is pushed to GitHub*" option has been renamed to "*GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling*" in most recent version of GitHub plugin. 
(thanks to @smrubin's feedback.)

Comment: How is this solved with blue ocean?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I suspect you missed the `webhook url`.

Besides checking the `Build when a change is pushed to GitHub` option, you should also add the webhook url into your Github repository to get the **Auto trigger** mechanism to work and here is how:

Go to your Github repository:

> Settings--> Webhooks&Services-->Service--> Add Services--> Choose "Jenkins (GitHub plugin)"

Then fill in the `Jenkins hook url` with your jenkins url like this:
http://your_jenkins_url/github-webhook/
[image]

---

And, **VERY IMPORTANT**, since you are installing your jenkins server in your localhost, please be aware that you **shouldn't** fill in above Jenkins hook url like `http://localhost:8080/github-webhook/` because Github is not able to recognize `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` or `192.168.*.*`.

**Either you should use an externally accessible DNS name or an IP address, which can be recognized by Github.**

Comment: This answer has come as a ray of hope :) I understand that I need to go to GitHub and  add service to by providing the Jenkins hook URL. I am confused what this <github-webhook>? How do I get that / configure the same?

Comment: Under GitHub WebHook(Jenkins Global Config), I found this 'http://localhost:8080/github-webhook/' and I believe thats what you were referring to. I need to figure out how to remove this localhost

Comment: @AnujBalan: were you able to figure out to remove the localhost?

Comment: Saved my time :) Great

Comment: how did u fix this? Where did u get the public ip from jenkins?

Comment: In my case it started working after installation of ParameterizeRemoteBuild plugin (Trigger Build remotely option) in build section.

Comment: @Perazim Use ngrok. [Setting up Jenkins on Ubuntu with Vagrant and accessing it on Internet with ngrok](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/eh2c/setting-up-jenkins-on-ubuntu-with-vagrant-and-accessing-it-on-internet-with-ngrok)

Comment: FYI, in most recent version of the GitHub plugin, this option has been renamed to "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling" https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Github+Plugin

Comment: Can I do this by adding Jenkins machine's ssh key in github?

Answer (score 45):

I had the same problem and solved it. The problem was that the URL had to end with a `/`. Meaning:

`http://<jenkinsurl>:8080/github-webhook/` ✅

`http://<jenkinsurl>:8080/github-webhook` ❌

(Notice the missing `/` at the end.)

Comment: Wow, fixed it for me too... thought I was going crazy

Comment: Seriously. Thanks!

Comment: This should be documented somewhere in red.

Answer (score 3):

Actually if you do the webhook settings from `Jenkins -> Github plugin configuration` (mentioned above), you will still see webhooks get created in github. So, above two approaches basically doing the same thing.

I personally like it to create webhook from Github, because in this way you don't have to share or store github user info in jenkins.

Steps :

1. Login into Github (with Admin)
2. Go to the repository you want to hook with jenkins
3. Click on settings tab -> webhooks & services
4. Click on Add Webhook.
5. Enter payload url : like : http://:8080/github-webhook/
6. Select content type as json.
7. you are done.

Now you do the changes and commit , you will see jenkins build get trigger automatically. Don't forget to do the settings in jenkins jobs to start the build when push code in github.

Answer (score 1):

The GitHub plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin) mentioned two ways: manual mode and automatic mode. mainframer gives the answer to the manual mode. Today I found something new. mainframer's add to the service doesn't allow me to add multiple Jenkins's instance, so I add the others add the Webhook as shown below. It also works fine.

I wanted to include a picture here but my id doesn't have the right to do so.