# Jenkins & Github, build maven project when change is pushed doesn't work

Tags: git, maven, github, jenkins, oauth

I try to follow several links and youtube video, example : 
[jenkins module](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin#GitHubPlugin-TriggerabuildwhenachangeispushedtoGitHub)

I tried several different ways to configure the settings but when I push change to github, jenkins don't build the maven project automatically.
However, from jenkins, I can build manually the project (so, there isn't problem between jenkins and my github)

Specifically, here are my current settings :

In Jenkins > manage Jenkins > Configure Systems > GitHub Web Hook block :
[image]

"Let Jenkins auto-manage hooks URLs" selected

Username : mygithubname

OAuth token : the token generated from github

In Github : 
global settings > personnal access tokens > my "jenkins" OAuth token : 
[image]
my repository > settings > Webhooks & Services > my "jenkins" service added
[image]

But I see an error in my repository > settings > Webhooks & services
"Last delivery was not successful. Service Timeout"
[image]

I come back in my jenkins settings :

Jenkins > Configure Global Security :
Enable security unchecked (nothing is checked in this page), I try to create a jenkins user like I see in some web tutorials..but with no success

Jenkins > my maven project > configuration :
[image]

Repository URL : https://github.com/mygithubname/myrepository.git

Credential : mygithubname/mygithubpassword

and "Build when a change is pushed to github checked

So..with this settings, where is my mistake ? 
Thank you =)

Comment: Are you able to get the solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a [blogpost with exact steps](http://lkrnac.net/blog/2014/03/continuous-delivery/) some time ago how to integrate Jenkins Github plugin with Github.

Scroll down to section "2. Jenkins – GitHub integration".

Differences I noticed between your and my approach:

1. I filled API URL in Github Web Hook section in Jenkins and didn't use username.
2. I didn't fill credentials in Jenkins job
3. Checked build trigger "Build when a change is pushed to Github" in Jenkins job

Comment: I test this changes, I push a new file...but nothing happen in jenkins :/ If I can, I will follow your tutorial

Answer (score 0):

What's the jenkins hook url you filled in the Github repo?

Github webhook mechanism rely on a public IP or DNS to work. So if you use `http://localhost:8080/github-webhook` or `http://127.0.0.1:8080/github-webhook` then it certainly not work, because Github not able to find where your jenkins is.

Comment: Any solution to overcome the same?

Comment: I have answered this question days ago, and you can feel free to take a look for the possible solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576881/jenkins-build-when-a-change-is-pushed-to-github-option-is-not-working/30577823#30577823

Comment: Because you are specifying this kind of url in Github. So Github will treat either `localhost:8080` and `127.0.0.1:8080` to itself, not your jenkins server. You should specify a public IP or DNS in order to get the Github webhook work. In other word, you should make sure Github can find your jenkins server from the internet. Both `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are invalid public address for other machines to look up.

Comment: In webhook github settings, the url used is the good (ip fixed of the jenkins server, with this ip I can access to my jenkins server from any computer/connection), not a local url