# How automated build or continuous integration can be made with jenkins and Github

Tags: git, github, jenkins

Jenkins is running on localhost. I have my repository in GitHub. I have the option to 'Build when a change is pushed to GitHub' checked.

When I click 'Build Now', build is done successfully, no issues there. But when am committing code to my repository, auto build is not happening. I can access GitHub from my system as the repository is public and I believe even Jenkins should be able to detect it. I know there is a polling option but I want Jenkins to build when change is detected in repository(as this is what we have been trying to achieve).

Configuration:

Jenkins 1.648

Git Plugin 2.6.3.windows.1

**THANKS IN ADVANCE**!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins-Build when a change is pushed to GitHub option is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576881/jenkins-build-when-a-change-is-pushed-to-github-option-is-not-working)

Comment: you can also look here: http://fourkitchens.com/blog/article/trigger-jenkins-builds-pushing-github