# How to enable auto-build on jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I am using Jenkins as my continuous integration tool. I have added my git repo on Jenkins and enabled "Build when a change is pushed to GitHub". But when we push to the github, the Jenkins job is not triggered automatically. Is there other place I need to configure in order to trigger Jenkins job?

Comment: Probably relevant to this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30576881/jenkins-build-when-a-change-is-pushed-to-github-option-is-not-working/30577823#30577823

Comment: Thanks for reply. The github need my jenkins webhook url. How can I set the url if my jenkins is in an internal web site which cannot be accessed from internet?

Comment: As far as I know, it is impossible. You have 2 options, either setup your jenkins with an public ip(or DNS) or setup an internal git server instead of github.